# On Windows, how to make a .bat or .ps1 file automatically elevate itself when running?

Tags: windows, command-line, permissions, script, runas

I have pinned admin cmd and admin pwsh to taskbar, I know how to run .bat files as Administrator, just right-click->"Run as administrator", for .ps1 files, I have modified openwith of .ps1 files so that the default program to open them is PSCore7, but right-clicking on them doesn't show a "Run as administrator" option, in order to run .ps1 as admin, I have to open admin pwsh and cd to $scriptdir (I put all my scripts in one folder) and run them like this:.\script.ps1;

How can I make a script(.bat and .ps1) automatically gain Administrator privileges when running so that I can just double click them and they run as admin automatically?

***AND*** some system folders and registry keys are inaccessible even with admin rights, they are only accessible to TrustedInstaller, I know how to gain access to them, for files and folders, use right-click->Properties->Security->Advanced to open "Advanced Security Settings for *" in explorer to take ownership and change permissions, for registry keys, use right-click->Permissions... in regedit to change permissions, or use icacls and cacls in cmd;

But this method is very risky, by using this method, somethings will stop working unpredictably somehow, for instance, taking ownership of C:\Windows\SystemApps will almost definitely render UWP apps unusable, and it can be hard to return ownership to TrustedInstaller;

I have Google searched for a way to run a script as TrustedInstaller, and found this:https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/run-program-as-trustedinstaller-locked-registry-keys-files/
It says I can use third party softwares like AdvancedRun, PowerRun, NSudo and ProcessHacker to run the console as TrustedInstaller and run the script, this is not what I wanted;

I want to modify the script itself to automatically gain TrustedInstaller privileges when running, without any 3rdP softwares, with as little user interaction as possible, so that I can just double click on them and they automatically give themselves TrustedInstaller privileges, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [make exe file automatically run as administrator](https://superuser.com/questions/797513/make-exe-file-automatically-run-as-administrator)

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio That will not work here, as you can't set compatibility options on executable scripts. Please don't VTC duplicate like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To execute as System use
[PsExec](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec).

The parameter to use is `PsExec -s`.